# Create an object from a valid JSON array with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I know my JSON is valid, I'm wanting to pull all the KEY's out of the array and put them in an object. However it seems I can either access ONE objects Key or Value, the entire array, or one key value pair. I have not figured out how to parse out all the keys, or all the values in the array.

Here is what I've tried:

print_r($json_obj) yields:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg [1] => featured ) [1] => Array ( [0] => uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg [1] => featured ) )
```

print_r($json_obj[0][1]) yields:

```
featured
```

print_r($json_obj[1][0]) yields:

```
uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg
```

print_r($json_obj[1][1]) yeilds:

```
featured
```

print_r($json_obj[0][0]) yields:

```
uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
        $resultSet = '[["uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg","featured"],
          ["uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg","featured"]]';
        $json_obj = json_decode($resultSet);
        // print_r($json_obj);
        print_r($json_obj[0][1]);

?>
```

The JSON validates per JSONLint

```
[
    [
        "uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg",
        "featured"
    ],
    [
        "uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg",
        "featured"
    ]
]
```

I would like to end up with a object with all the keys in the json_obj... ie:

```
json_obj = array(
        'uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg',
        'uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg'
);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? `json_decode` properly decodes the given JSON - if you want something different, you can easily iterate over the the array and create your new result.

Comment: What is your input and the expected output? Make it clear.

Comment: My input is hard coded to the resultSet= " ";

My expected output is an array of the file paths (the keys) from the JSON.... something similar to the json_obj = array(); example at the end

Answer (score 1):

If your input is always in the same format, you can handle it like this

```
$tmp = json_decode($resultSet);
$json_obj = array();
foreach ($tmp as $values) {
    array_push($json_obj, $values[0]);
}
```

This will give you `$json_obj` in the desired format with a hardcoded `$resultSet` like the one you provided.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you are looking for:

json encode server-side like:

```
 echo json_encode($html);
```

json parse clientside like

```
 var str = JSON.parse(data);
 alert (JSON.stringify(str))
```

Comment: Not quite, the json I'm passing to the script is already encoded via ajax. For the purposes of this post, I hard coded what my javascript would be passing to the php script (which works elsewhere). Since I know what my script is passing, I felt it was safe to hard code the values. I am simply trying to access the keys from each json object and build a object so I can use it later.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it like this:

Changing the json object to this format

```
data = { gallery: gallery_name, 
           files: [
                     // imagefile,imagefile,imagefile...
                   ] 
        };
```

And the using the following php

```
    $resultSet = json_decode($_GET['submittedResults'], true);
    $gallery = $resultSet['gallery'];
    $files_to_zip = $resultSet['files'];
```